# Android: Display same text output to multiple EditText

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-edittext

Let's say I have a single text output, for example "This is an EditText"(textToUse).

I want to display this same text output into not 1, but multiple EditText fields.

If I have 3 EditText ids: edit1, edit2 and edit3

Instead of using just:

```
private EditText mEditText;
private String textToUse;

mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1);
mEditText.setText(textToUse);
```

which will only display the text output to EditText "edit1", how can I change the codes to make it display on "edit2" and "edit3" as well?

I have tried:

```
mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1);
mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit2);
mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit3);
```

and

```
mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1, R.id.edit2, R.id.edit3);
```

and

```
mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1, edit2, edit3);
```

but none of them works. 
I apologise if this is a stupid question, I have just started Android Development. Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare three different EditText on your code, non-array object can hold only one(1) values. So:

```
mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1);
mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit2);
mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit3);
```

will simply overrides its values. (In above code mEditText only holds the R.id.edit3)

Try

```
mEditText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1);
mEditText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit2);
mEditText3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit3);
mEditText1.setText(textToUse);
mEditText2.setText(textToUse);
mEditText3.setText(textToUse);
```

Or use an array for your EditText as @Huy Nguyen did in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many of EditText, you can try to create an array of EditText, ID array of every EditText.

ex:

```
EditText []et;
int []idEt = {R.id.et1, R.id.et2, R.id.et3.....};
```

Then use a loop statement to do anything..
ex:

```
for(int i=0; i<numberOfEditText; i++){
   et[i] = (EditText)findViewById(idEt[i]);
}
```

....

```
for(int i=0; i<numberOfEditText; i++){
   et[i].setText("abcdefghi");
}
```

You can save many lines of code.
Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you so much. But I will be using @FrozenFire answer as it is easier for me to implement :)

Comment: You're welcome! But when you have too many EditText, my solution is best because you can save many lines of code. You should try both solution to know how it works. A nice day to you! :)